# Algebra Value based on condition provided

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Let $a, b, c$ be distinct real numbers such that 
$a^2 - b = b^2 - c = c^2 - a$

Then $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$ equals?

I attempted manipulations with that condition provided, but then I'm unable to go anywhere worthwhile.
I tried expanding the product given but I couldn't see where to apply the condition.
How must I begin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a^2-b=b^2-c$ so $(a-b)(a+b)=b-c$. Similarly $(a-c)(a+c)=b-a$ and $(b-c)(b+c)=c-a$. Hence we obtain that:
$$
(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=\frac{(b-c)(b-a)(c-a)}{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)}=1
$$